# Setting absolute height of y axis in plotly bar

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I am using plotly (python) in Dash to create a **bar** plot. I want to set the absolute height of the yaxis (not the full plot).

So each bar should have a maximum height of x pixels and the whole plot area including the tick labels can expand as necessary for the labels.

Is this possible?

[figure explaining desired height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pKKh.png)